# php deprecated function removal and repclacement problems

Tags: php, regex, posix, pcre, deprecated

I am trying to replace the deprecated functions in my PHP source code with new recommended ones. But I was having a big problem with replacing eregi function with preg_match function with an "i" in the regex pattern as suggested in the php manual. Here is the sample code:

```
<?php

$strXml=<<<XMLSTRING
  ALIPC231232

  TIME



  Jan 21 10:43:58 UTC 2011



  ORIGINAL REQUEST:

  TIME PLEASE



XMLSTRING;

eregi("(TIME)(.*)(ORIGINAL REQUEST:)" , $strXml, $matches);
echo "begin_ck_eregi_match1:".$matches[1].":end_ck_eregi_match1";
echo "begin_ck_eregi_match2:".$matches[2].":end_ck_eregi_match2";

preg_match("/(TIME)(.*)(ORIGINAL REQUEST:)/i" , $strXml, $match);
echo "begin_ck_preg_match_match1:".$match[1].":end_ck_preg_match_match1";
echo "begin_ck_preg_match_match2:".$match[2].":end_ck_preg_match_match2";

?>
```

In the above code, eregi gave matches properly when a string is tested against a pattern; but when preg_match is used over the same string and tested it against the same pattern no matches are returned. I am unable to figure out why? I must me missing something here. Request you to please help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot `.` won't match new-lines. Additionally, use the `s` modifier (called [`PCRE_DOTALL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)):

```
preg_match('/(TIME)(.*)(ORIGINAL_REQUEST:)/is', $strXml, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`eregi() function`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) makes case-**in**sensitive search. You'll have to use [PCRE `i` modifier](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to achieve the same results.

```
eregi("(TIME)(.*)(ORIGINAL REQUEST:)" , $strXml, $matches)

preg_match('/(TIME)(.*)(ORIGINAL REQUEST\:)/si', $strXml, $matches);
```

Comment: I see that I was not using the "s" modifier earlier. When I used the "s" modifier as in Crozin's example, it worked just fine. Thanks a lot.